# Break an external while loop from an inner for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I want to break the outer while loop when the condition `stop=true` is reached in the inner for loop. Is this possible?

```
urlsToScrape.addAll(startUrls);

    boolean stop=false;

    while(stop==false){
        for(Link url:urlsToScrape){
p.rint(url.depth+" >= "+depth);
            if(url.depth>=depth){
                p.rint("STOP!");
                stop=true;
                break;
            }
p.rint("scrape(): "+url.link+" / "+url.depth);
            processLinks(url.link,url.depth);
            urlsToScrape.remove(url);
            scrapedUrls.add(url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(!stop){` is a better style than `while(stop==false){`

Comment: Isn't that what already happens? The entire body of the `while` loop is the `for` loop, so if you set `stop` to `true` inside that, then break out of it, the `while` loop will stop iterating.

Comment: Sorry this is a duplicate. Feel free to vote to close.

Comment: @Anthony I thought that was how it should work, but it didn't seem to. The label technique worked.

Comment: jlordo +1 - you're right.

Answer (score 10):

Use a label :

```
 outofthere:
 while (stop==false){
      for(Link url:urlsToScrape){
            p.rint(url.depth+" >= "+depth);
            if(url.depth>=depth){
                p.rint("STOP!");
                stop=true;
                break outofthere;
            }
            p.rint("scrape(): "+url.link+" / "+url.depth);
            processLinks(url.link,url.depth);
            urlsToScrape.remove(url);
            scrapedUrls.add(url);
      }
  }
```

See [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Comment: +1. I always forget to use label in loop and sometimes they are very useful.

Comment: @Ankur Just waiting for what exactly ? :)